# How to sum the data Category wise in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkNGj.jpg)I have this type of data and i can sum of the data category wise how can i do it.i try to do it but the data is sum like 100+100 =100100 but i can do 100  + 100 =200
Help me solve the error if you know

```
df.groupby(['Category'])['Installs'].agg('sum')
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to convert the column to an integer dtype before attempting to sum.

Comment: It means column is string repr of numbers, convert them to numbers like dupe.

Comment: what is the code?

Comment: See the answer to question that yours was marked a duplicate of. It has the code you need.